# Java Generics, Linked List

Tags: java, generics, serialization, singly-linked-list

I finished learning Generics and I didn't find it easy. However , I did understand it. Here is what I understood. I want you to correct me where I am wrong and answer a few questions :) .

```
public class LinkedList<T> {
//class definition
}
```

This means that LinkedList<> is a class that will accept objects of classes and also interfaces.

```
public class LinkedList<T extends Object> {
//class definition
}
```

This means that LinkedList<> is a class that will accept objects of those classes **only** that extend Object class. Basically, all classes. In case of a raw type, T will be replaced by Object

```
public class LinkedList<T extends Object & java.lang.Serializable> {
//class definition
}
```

This means that LinkedList<> is a class that accepts objects of **all** those classes that implement Serializable interface. If an object of user defined class has to be included in the list then the user defined class **must** implement Serializable.

```
public class LinkedList<T> implements Iterable<T> {
//class definition
}
```

This means that the LinkedList<> class can be used with a collection-based for loop. It must overload iterator() method and should have an inner class that implements `Itarator<T>` and overloads hasNext(), next() and remove()

*Questions*
1. Please explain the meaning of this in simple words and with an example, if possible:
    public class `BinaryTree<T extends Comparable<? super T>>`  what replaces the ?
2. I want to write the above mentioned LinkedList<> class to a file using the writeObject() method. so I declare it as

```
public class LinkedList<T extends Object> implements Serializable {
     //methods and data members      
private class Node implements Serializable { //inner class
                  T object;
                  Node next;
           }
    }
```

Does the inner class have to implement Serializable as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About your four first points:

1. A list that is is supposed to contain instances of `T` (including classes that extend `T`).
2. Actually identical to the first one, as all classes extend `Object`.
3. A list that can only contain objects that are `Serializable` (same as `class LinkedList<T extends Serializable> { ... }`)
4. An iterable list of `T`, so yeah, it can be used in enhanced loops.

Worth noting, when we say "a list that can only contain objects of the specified type", we should say "should" instead of "can". Unless you pass `Class<?>` objects around, Java (runtime) will not check the values passed in actually comply, only the compiler will, and only based on the visible static type, which could've been manually changed (that'd issue a warning).

About the questions:

1. It represents a `BinaryTree` that contains objects that are `Comparable` to any object of the same class as `T` or any of its supertypes (`Object` is one supertype of all classes, essentially all classes that `T` extends and all interfaces it implements).
2. If you want to serialize the object using `writeObject`, then all non-transient (i.e. that you cannot rebuild based on other data) instance fields of that object need to be `Serializable` as well, or [`writeObject` will ignore them](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html). Your code extract isn't quite sufficient to tell whether `Node` needs to be `Serializable` or not, but it probably needs to given the general idea of the `List` example.

Comment: @FasihKhatib Indication of whether the `LinkedList` has a non-static field of type `Node`.

Comment: I was planning on adding a non-static method `public void writeIt()` that would create an `ObjectOutputStream` and then use the `writeObject(this)`

Comment: Yes, it will have non-statics `Node start` that points to the start of the list, `Node end` to point to the end of the list. `Node current` to point to the current node.

Comment: The three: start, end and current are required for traversal of the list.

Comment: So then, Node needs to be Serializable.

Answer (score 1):

To add some clarifications:

`T` stands for any reference type; it could be a class, or interface, or array, or it could be a parameterized type. There is no distinction between classes and interfaces etc.

`T extends Object` is the same as `T` because every reference type is a subtype of `Object` (yes, interfaces are subtypes of `Object` too). `extends Object` is sort of redundant.

`T extends Object & Serializable` requires `T` to be a subtype of both `Object` and `Serializable`. Since as we said before, everything is a subtype of `Object`, for now you can consider it to be the same as `T extends Serializable` (it's slightly different because in the first case the erasure of `T` will be `Object` and in the second case `Serializable`; but you don't need to worry about this at this point).

Answer (score 0):

From Oracle guidelines:

> Note - Serialization of inner classes (i.e., nested classes that are not static member classes), including local and anonymous classes, is strongly discouraged for several reasons. Because inner classes declared in non-static contexts contain implicit non-transient references to enclosing class instances, serializing such an inner class instance will result in serialization of its associated outer class instance as well. Synthetic fields generated by javac (or other JavaTM compilers) to implement inner classes are implementation dependent and may vary between compilers; differences in such fields can disrupt compatibility as well as result in conflicting default serialVersionUID values. The names assigned to local and anonymous inner classes are also implementation dependent and may differ between compilers. Since inner classes cannot declare static members other than compile-time constant fields, they cannot use the serialPersistentFields mechanism to designate serializable fields. Finally, because inner classes associated with outer instances do not have zero-argument constructors (constructors of such inner classes implicitly accept the enclosing instance as a prepended parameter), they cannot implement Externalizable. None of the issues listed above, however, apply to static member classes.

[Serializible Interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/serial-arch.html#4539), [Defining Serializable Fields for a Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/serial-arch.html#6250)